Who is the first Asura?
Well, most of us know about Asuras. But, i had a doubt that who is the first Asura. So, my question is, Who is the first Asura and what is his story?

Diatyas, Danvas and Rakshashas are collectively called Asuras.

Hiraṇyakaśipu was the first among Daityas (descendent of Diti). ~ Harivamsha Purana: Bhavishya Parva

Vipracitti was first among Danavas (descendant of Danu). ~ Is Maya Dānava the first Dānava?

Heti was the first among Rakshashas. ~ How were Rakshas created?


